# Efficient Algorithm to Compute The Summation of the Function

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, time-complexity

We are given **N** points of the form **(x,y)** and we need to compute the following function:

## F(i,j) = ( | X[i] - X[j] | ) * ( | Y[i] - Y[j] | )

## Compute Summation of F(i,j) for all ordered pairs (i,j)

### N <= 300000

I am looking for a `O(N log N)` solution.

My initial thought was to sort the points by X and then use a BIT but I'm not being able to formulate a clear solution.

Comment: Look, if all the pairs lead to different value of F(i,j), there is no way to do it in O(N log N) height, kindly post the link to contest in comment.

Comment: You know that all values for `i = i` are zero.  You also know that symmetry holds: `F(i, j) = F(j, i)`.

Comment: @duffymo OP never said anything about i=j are 0.

Comment: @Dante - Typo; should have read i=i.  Since x[i]-x[i]=y[i]-y[i]=0

Comment: No, my typo.  Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Can you link to the contest problem please?

Comment: This problem was in one of the APIO Practice Tests ; I don't think we can submit now :(

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution using `O(N log(M))` time and `O(M)` memory, where `M` is the size of range of `Y`. It's similar to what you are thinking.

First sort the points so that the `X` coordinates are increasing.

Let's write `A` for the sum of `(X[i] - X[j]) * (Y[i] - Y[j])` for all pairs `i > j` such that `Y[i] > Y[j]`, and `B` for the sum of the same expression for all pairs `i > j` such that `Y[i] < Y[j]`.

The sum `A + B` can be calculated easily in `O(N)` time, and the final answer can be calculated from `A - B`. Thus it suffices to calculate `A`.

Now create a binary indexed tree, whose nodes are indexed by intevals of the form `[a, b)` with `b = a + 2^k` for some `k`. (Not a good sentance, but you know what I mean, right?) The root node should cover the inteval `[Y_min, Y_max]` of possible values of `Y`.

For any node indexed by `[a, b)` and for any `i`, let `f(a, b, i)` be the following polynomial:

`f(a, b, i)(X, Y) = sum of (X - X[j]) * (Y - Y[j]) for all j such that j < i and Y[j] < Y`

It is of the form `P * XY + Q * X + R * Y + S`, thus such a polynomial can be represented by the four numbers `P, Q, R, S`.

Now beginning with `i = 0`, you may calculate `f(a, b, i)(X[i], Y[i])`. To go from `i` to `i + 1`, you only need to update those intevals `[a, b)` containing `Y[i]`. When you reach `i = N`, the value of `A` is calculated.

If you can afford `O(M)` memory, then this should work fine.

Comment: You can also compress the Y coordinates and get O(N) memory and O(N log N) time

Comment: Probably, one can pre-sort the `Y` values.